# set_where_condition en Comboboxdelegate con valor seleccionado en otro comboboxdelegate

Tags: c++, qt

tengo dos `comboboxdelegates`.

```
 BlGenericComboBoxDelegate *cbd_id_tipo_tubo = new BlGenericComboBoxDelegate(mainCompany(), this);
    cbd_id_tipo_tubo->set_foreign_table("presu.tipo_tubo", "id", "tipo");
    cbd_id_tipo_tubo->set_foreign_field(columnNumber("id_tipo_tubo"), "id_tipo_tubo");
    cbd_id_tipo_tubo->setAllowNull(false);
    cbd_id_tipo_tubo->initialize("_tubo");
    mui_list->setItemDelegateForColumn(columnNumber("_tubo"), cbd_id_tipo_tubo);




BlGenericComboBoxDelegate *cbd_id_tipo_medida = new BlGenericComboBoxDelegate(mainCompany(), this);
    cbd_id_tipo_medida->set_foreign_table("presu.medidas_tipo_tubo","id", "medida");
cbd_id_tipo_medida->set_foreign_field(columnNumber("id_medidas_tipo_tubo"), "id_medidas_tipo_tubo"); 

cbd_id_tipo_medida->set_where_condition( 

**AQUI VALOR DEL PRIMER COMBO (id_tipo_tubo));

    cbd_id_tipo_medida->setAllowNull(false);
    cbd_id_tipo_medida->initialize("_medida");
    mui_list->setItemDelegateForColumn(columnNumber("_medida"), cbd_id_tipo_medida);
```

Estos *combobox* aparecen en una línea de un sub-formulario `Qtableview`, y quiero que el *item* seleccionado en el primer *combobox* sea el `where` del segundo.

He probado con `currenttext` y demás, pero son de `combobox`, no de `comboboxdelegate` y no consigo hacerme con el `id_tipo_tubo` del primer `comboboxdelegate`.

Gracias

Comment: por favor use las etiquetas adecuadas.

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso, se soluciona de esta manera. Ya que faltaba la referencia de la columna del id de la clave foranea del combobox.

Añadiendo esta linea en el combobox, se soluciona.

```
cbd_id_tipo_medida->set_filter_id("id_tipo_tubo", "id_tipo_tubo", true);
```

Comment: dale editar, pues debes explicar tu respuesta, solo colocar código es de baja calidad

Comment: [Te pueden votar negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)